# livefyre Won't Center on Page

Tags: css, livefyre

I use a livefyre comments box on my website. My website is designed for a max-width of 980px. I set the livefyre comments box also to a max-width of 980px, but can't seem to get it to horizontally center on the page. I have tried using margin:0 auto; and text-align:center; I set up a test page with inline CSS code at http://www.romancestuck.com/test-pages/livefyre-center.htm

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

URL based question are not suggested, post code next time,

for current solution,add this

```
#livefyre-comments{
  width:60%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

**Problem is** that your container ( *`#livefyre-comments` in this case* ) has no width set, so it takes the entire available width of view-port.....set a width and then setting margin will center the thing because logically speaking, you can not center something which is 100% wide!! :)

Comment: I actually figured it out right after asking the question. I put:

    #livefyre-comments
    {
      margin:0 auto;
      max-width:980px;
    }

Thanks!

Comment: @WebStuck : happens with we all the time....meanwhile,do u mind marking an answer as accepted...it will suggest question has been answered!! :)

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code:

```
 .fire { margin:0 auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to center the main container:

```
.fyre {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```